# Why is coldfusion outputting these values as floating point decimals?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm experiencing difficulties with a jwt token, turns out it's because coldfusion is converting an int to a float. I'm not sure where the problem is or how to fix it.

Token timestamp and expiration:

```
<cfset TimeStamp = '#VAL( int( getTickCount() / 1000 ) )#' > 
<cfset Exp = '#VAL( int( (getTickCount() / 1000)+43200 ) )#' > 

    <cfscript>
        Variables.payload                = StructNew();
        Variables.payload[ "nbf" ]       = "#TimeStamp#";
        Variables.payload[ "exp" ]       = "#Exp#";
        Variables.result                 = JWT.encode( payload, Variables.secretKey);
     </cfscript>
```

The JWT.Encode call looks like this:

```
<cffunction name="encode" access="public" returntype="String">
    <!--- ****************** Arguments ************************ --->
    <cfargument name="payload" type="any" required="true">
    <cfargument name="key" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="algo" type="string" required="false" default="HS256">
    <!--- ****************** /Arguments *********************** --->

    <!--- define our variables here  --->
    <cfset var currentTime = getCurrentUtcTime()>
    <cfset var header = createObject("java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap").init() /> <!--- StructNew doesnt work because coldfusion 8 orders the keys --->
    <cfset var claims = createObject("java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap").init() /> <!--- StructNew doesnt work because coldfusion 8 orders the keys --->
    <cfset var segments = ArrayNew(1)>

    <!---
        creation of first segment of our JWT: the header
    --->
    <cfset header[ "typ" ] = "JWT">
    <cfset header[ "alg" ] = "HS256">
    <!--- add header an json with base64 encoding to segment array --->
    <cfset arrayAppend( segments, replace( toBase64( serializeJSON( header ) ), "=", "", "all" ) )>

    <!---
        creation of the middle segment: the claims set
    --->
    <cfset claims = Arguments.payload>
    <!---
        escape forward slashes in generated JSON
    --->
    <cfset claimsJson = replace(  serializeJSON( claims ), "/", "\/", "all" )>

    <!--- add header and json with base64 encoding (with padding REMOVED!) to segment array --->
    <cfset arrayAppend( segments, replace( toBase64( claimsJson ), "=", "", "all" ) )>

    <!---
        create the last segment: the signature
    --->
    <cfset signingInput = ArrayToList( segments, "." )>
    <cfset signature = sign( signingInput, Arguments.key, Arguments.algo )>

    <!---
        add signature as last the element to our string
    --->
    <cfreturn ListAppend( signingInput, signature, ".")>

</cffunction>
```

Run through a base64 decoder, I get something like exp":1.498696809E9,"nbf":1.498653609E9

Comment: Step 1 - dump timestamp and see if it's an integer or floating point decimal.  If it looks like scientific notation, use numberformat().

Comment: Well it doesn't have the notation until the serializeJSON, if I dump before then, it's numeric.

Comment: `serializeJSON` is notorious for butchering numbers. What version of CF you are on?

Comment: CF 10. I'm not surprised it does that. I image there's not much I can do about it?

Comment: I wrote myself a serializer which is type sensitive, meaning I just cast the non-string values using [`javaCast()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fbe.html) and then reflect them in the serializer with `.getClass().getName()` to stringify them properly. I can share the code, if you are interested.

Comment: If you don't have time to write a serializer yourself, Ben Nadel did. Try it: https://github.com/bennadel/JsonSerializer.cfc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get [Nathan Mische's JSONUtil.cfc](https://github.com/CFCommunity/jsonutil). Then replace the line

```
<cfset claimsJson = replace(  serializeJSON( claims ), "/", "\/", "all" )>
```

with

```
<cfset jsonTool = createobject("component","jsonutil")>
<cfset claimsJson = replace(jsonTool.serializeJSON(claims,false,true), "/", "\/", "all" )>
```